# Hideous loss of data while passing a matrix into a function (OpenCV 2.4.6 & Qt 4.8.4)

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, matrix

I have been battling a hideous problem involving loss of matrix data as the matrix (Mat) is passed as an argument into into one of my custom functions.

The problem caught me by some surprise, because it did not show up while running my sample program (compiled with Visual Studio 2012) stand-alone. In case of the stand-alone application, the data was passed through and processed just fine. The problem only showed up, when the sample application was compiled into a static library (.lib) and linked into a master application running under Qt 4.8.4.

### Essential Code

#### Master Application

```
IMPORTED_IMAGE_bin.copyTo( FOREGR_BUFFER_CONNECTORS );
imwrite( "FOREGR_BUFFER_CONNECTORS1.png", FOREGR_BUFFER_CONNECTORS );
...
ind_Contours_Validate( IMPORTED_IMAGE, ..., FOREGR_BUFFER_CONNECTORS, ...);
```

#### Header File

```
void        Find_Contours_Validate(
                Mat                         IMPORTED_IMAGE,
                ...
                Mat                         &FOREGR_BUFFER_CONNECTORS );
```

#### Function Definition

```
void        Find_Contours_Validate(
                Mat                         IMPORTED_IMAGE,
                ...
                Mat                         &FOREGR_BUFFER_CONNECTORS )
{
    ...
    imwrite( "FOREGR_BUFFER_CONNECTORS2.png", FOREGR_BUFFER_CONNECTORS );
}
```

### Key Observations

1. For most buffers, the data is passed into and out of the function Find_Contours_Validate() just fine.
2. FOREGR_BUFFER_CONNECTORS contains expected data right before the call to Find_Contours_Validate().
3. FOREGR_BUFFER_CONNECTORS is empty right after the call to Find_Contours_Validate().
4. IMPORTED_IMAGE contains the expected data right after the call to Find_Contours_Validate().

### Alternatives Considered

1. I have tried passing the buffer FOREGR_BUFFER_CONNECTORS both by reference and by value:

   > Mat &FOREGR_BUFFER_CONNECTORS vs. Mat FOREGR_BUFFER_CONNECTORS.
2. I have tried creating an explicit copy of the data in the function call:

   Find_Contours_Validate( IMPORTED_IMAGE, ..., FOREGR_BUFFER_CONNECTORS.clone(), ...);
3. I have tried passing an empty buffer into the function but copy the data inside the function:

> void      Find_Contours_Validate(
>   
>   Mat                           IMPORTED_IMAGE,
>   
>   Mat                           IMPORTED_IMAGE_bin,
>   
>   ...
>   
>   Mat                           &FOREGR_BUFFER_CONNECTORS )
>   
>   {
>   
>         ...
>   
>          IMPORTED_IMAGE_bin.copyTo( FOREGR_BUFFER_CONNECTORS );
>   
>         imwrite( "FOREGR_BUFFER_CONNECTORS2.png", FOREGR_BUFFER_CONNECTORS );
>   
>     }

--> The observation is always the same: **FOREGR_BUFFER_CONNECTORS shows up fine outside the function call but as empty inside.**

As I say: *The problem only shows up when I run the code as a static library linked into an integrated application (not when I run it stand-alone).*

Any suggestions?

Comment: `I have tried passing the buffer FOREGR_BUFFER_CONNECTORS both by argument and by value:`  What do you mean by passing `by argument`?  There is no such thing in C++ as "passing by argument".

Comment: How do you observe values of the offending matrix? Since `Mat` is nothing more but a reference-counting smart pointer, it makes little sense to pass it by reference most of the time.

Comment: I meant to say pass by value or pass by reference, as indicated by the sample statement: `Mat FOREGR_BUFFER_CONNECTORS vs. Mat &FORGR_BUFFER_CONNECTORS`